# Do any female Hirogen hunt?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

According to the episode Prey, Hirogen culture and mythology revolve around hunting dangerous aliens, and in the previous episode Hunters, one Hirogen says a rare trophy would make him "envied by men and pursued by women"- so is hunting strictly a "boy's only" club among the Hirogen species?

Answer (score 1):

### Main Canon

We don't see any female Hirogen in any of the shows or films.

We learn (via Memory Alpha) in an interview in [*Star Trek: The Magazine*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hirogen) that staff writer Raf Green pitched making the character of [Donik](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Donik) (the technician seen in *VOY: Flesh and Blood*) a Hirogen female, but this didn't ultimately happen.

---

### Extended Universe

Moving down the canon scale we learn in the [*Star Trek: RPG - Decipher: Aliens Module*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Aliens_(Decipher)) that Hirogen hunters are exclusively male.

> Hirogen culture degenerated to the point where **most males travel the
> galaxy in two-person ships, seeking suitable victims**. Sometimes a
> number of these ships team up when chasing an especially challenging
> or unusual quarry. Individually, the Hirogen prove more than a match
> for most opponents. Working together, they have little difficulty
> against any foe.

And that Hirogen females (and their offspring) cluster around central facilities. They don't hunt.

> Some Hirogen realize the inherent instability in their way of life,
> but none want to see the hunt ended. One visionary Hirogen obtained
> Federation holoprogramming in order to simulate hunts, allowing his
> race its traditional activities, but without the nomadic structure
> it forced on them. The Hirogen added this to a number of their
> training facilities, but many Hirogen still hunt the traditional way.
> **Women and children remain at central points like these training
> facilities, but their ability to remain in communication has suffered a dramatic setback when a Federation ship destroyed the ancient
> communications array they used to stay in touch with the hunters.**